# Can't reindex with sunspot / solr in rails app - Error: Severe errors in solr configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Ok, so I have a simple rails application and now i'm trying to implement sunspot for search capabilities. However, after I've generated the config file with rails g sunspot_rails:install and after I've started the server and it has made the solr-dir in my rails app-dir and i run bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex I get the following trace:

```
cakism@saraswati:~/railscode/calendar$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex --trace
** Invoke sunspot:solr:reindex (first_time)
** Invoke sunspot:reindex (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:reindex
Skipping progress bar: for progress reporting, add gem 'progress_bar' to your Gemfile
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error: Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

 <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in null

-------------------------------------------------------------

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Event</query></delete>"

Backtrace: /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:230:in `adapt_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:167:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
(eval):2:in `post'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:131:in `delete_by_query'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:55:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:230:in `adapt_response'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:167:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
(eval):2:in `post'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:67:in `update'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-1.0.7/lib/rsolr/client.rb:131:in `delete_by_query'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:55:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:181:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot.rb:464:in `remove_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:178:in `solr_remove_all_from_index'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:197:in `solr_reindex'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:54
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:53
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
```

I am specially curious about this:

```
If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

 <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in null
```

Why would it say in null? Other posts with the same problem as I have has specified the solr/conf/solrconfig.xml, and also, when I change it to false, nothing else happens.

If I remove the searchable block from my model, I don't get any error (but I suppose that's because it doesn't try to do anything then)

I've run the config file through an XML validator, and it says it's bad start-tag name at 2<-1 5<-2 6<90%. 
However, even if I remove the lines which then gives a valid XML, restart solr, and try to reindex, I still get the same error.

I'm starting to get desperate here, so any help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: I am facing a similar problem Did you ever get around fixing this issue? Thanks for help

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever resolve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having a very similar problem and solved it by

- stopping all running solr processes
- removing the solr folder
- turn off/restart the computer
- gem uninstall all related gems
- bundle install
- start solr
- reindex solr

Comment: Simply deleting the ./solr directory (the whole folder, not just the contents) fixed it for me.

Comment: adding the step rails generate sunspot_rails:install before start solr, and keeping the old solr files in case you need some old config, your solution worked and saved me! Thanks

Comment: Oh also, no need to restart the computer in my case at least.

Comment: @foz, thank you for pointed me in the right direction. deleting the solr folder was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

it happened to me occasionally.. in my case it was solr (not sunspot) issue

try to go to

```
http://localhost:8982/solr/admin

or http://localhost:8983/solr/admin

or http://[your.domain]:8983/solr/admin
```

(depending on what environment you use)

to see what error you have under solr web server

i saw the java error message and fixed it with just deleting index directory and restarting solr

and it began to behave as expected

hope it helped

Answer (score 2):

or you can re install the gem. This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the easy way (**does not require messing with gems or restarting computer**):

```
rake sunspot:solr:stop
```

If you have modified the schema, copy the contents of `site_root/solr/conf/schema.xml` to your clipboard

Next, delete the entire solr folder at `site_root/solr`

Now run:

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

This command will create and repopulate the deleted solr folder.

If you copied schema.xml above, open schema.xml again, select everything, and copy the contents of your clipboard. Save the file.

Now run:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, I found out the cause for my problem, hope this helps any souls who was wondering what happened

First, I deleted the solr/data folder. Bad idea. And this caused the errors as described by cakism.

Restarting, deleting solr folder, etc. won't help. Simply because there is an instance of Solr server running and it will not be stopped even with sunspot:solr:stop. You have to kill that instance by:

```
rake sunspot:solr:stop # stop server
ps -A | grep solr      # you'll see the [PID] of the solr server
kill [PID]             # replace with the [PID] from above to completely kill the solr instance
```

After this, you can then proceed with deleting the solr folder and starting the server again

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, and finally I got config/database.yml has wrong database name and, than I checked sunspot.yml, this file has also wrong configuration like ip address. I modify both of file than it start to work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was so much dependency with `turn off/restart the computer`(It was not possible to restart) and does not work any thing from above(I am not trying with restart). So, my working solution was

1. Go to app root directory.
2. using `ps aux | grep solr` find solr `process ID`
3. stop solr process using `kill -9 4313` # for me 4313 was solr process id
4. start solr on staging `rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=staging`
5. re-index solr using `rake sunspot:solr:reindex RAILS_ENV=staging`

That's it.

N.B:  **Replace environment according your need**